# Alpha Beta prune for chess always returning the first move in the list

Tags: haskell, artificial-intelligence, alpha-beta-pruning

I am writing a minimax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning for chess and cannot get the algorithm to return anything but the first move that it generates.  I have been knocking my head against but cannot figure out what is going wrong.  The code is a bit messy and in dire need of refactoring, but maybe you can see something that I am not.

I have verified that my evalNaive' function works as expected (very simple, just evaluate the board based on material).

```
alphaBeta :: Game -> Move
alphaBeta g = maxGame $ map (\mv -> (abMinNode 4 (-100) 100 (move g mv), mv)) (nextMoves g)
        where maxGame = snd . foldr foldingF (-100, Move (Coord 1 1) (Coord 1 1))
              foldingF x y = if fst x < fst y then y else x

abMaxNode :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Game -> Int
abMaxNode 0 a b (Just (Game brd _ trn)) = evalNaive' brd trn
abMaxNode d a b (Just g) = abMaxHelper d (-100) a b g $ nextMoves g

abMaxHelper :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Game -> [Move] -> Int
abMaxHelper d v a b g [] = v
abMaxHelper d v a b g (x:xs)
        | b <= newA = v
        | otherwise = abMaxHelper d newV newA b g xs
                where newV = max v (abMinNode (d - 1) a b (move g x))
                      newA = max a newV

abMinNode :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Maybe Game -> Int
abMinNode 0 a b (Just (Game brd _ trn)) = evalNaive' brd trn
abMinNode d a b (Just g) = abMinHelper d 100 a b g $ nextMoves g 

abMinHelper :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Game -> [Move] -> Int
abMinHelper d v a b g [] = v
abMinHelper d v a b g (x:xs)
        | newB <= a = v
        | otherwise = abMinHelper d newV a newB g xs
                where newV = min v (abMaxNode (d - 1) a b (move g x))
                      newB = min b newV


nextMoves :: Game -> [Move]
nextMoves g = filterLegal $ concatMap (possibleMoves g) allSpaces
        where filterLegal = foldr (\cur lst -> case move g cur of
                Nothing -> lst
                _ -> cur:lst) []
```

EDIT:

Definitions for some of my data types:

```
data Coord = Coord Int Int deriving (Eq)
data Move = Move Coord Coord deriving (Eq)
data Game = Game Board Flags Color deriving (Eq)
```

where Flags is a list of strings telling you things like for example white's queenside rook can castle, and Color is the color of whose turn it is.

EDIT2:

Here are the results of calling alphaBeta minus maxGame $, yielding the list of tuples containing scores and the moves that got them:

(A coordinate (x,y) is the x file and y rank)

```
Just [(0,(1,7) => (1,6)),
      (0,(1,7) => (1,5)),
      (0,(2,7) => (2,6)),
      (0,(2,7) => (2,5)),
      (0,(2,8) => (1,6)),
      (0,(2,8) => (3,6)),
      (0,(3,7) => (3,6)),
      (0,(3,7) => (3,5)),
      (0,(4,7) => (4,6)),
      (0,(4,7) => (4,5)),
      (0,(5,7) => (5,6)),
      (0,(5,7) => (5,5)),
      (0,(6,7) => (6,6)),
      (0,(6,7) => (6,5)),
      (0,(7,7) => (7,6)),
      (0,(7,7) => (7,5)),
      (0,(7,8) => (6,6)),
      (0,(7,8) => (8,6)),
      (0,(8,7) => (8,6)),
      (0,(8,7) => (8,5))]
```

As you can see, they are all coming back as 0. Knowing that evalNaive' works, the issue is somewhere in the recursive functions.

EDIT3:
Ran the same code with a depth of 5 and got this list of potential moves:

```
[(-1,(1,7) => (1,6)),
(-1,(1,7) => (1,5)),
(-1,(2,7) => (2,6)),
(-3,(2,7) => (2,5)),
(-3,(2,8) => (1,6)),
(-1,(2,8) => (3,6)),
(-1,(3,7) => (3,6)),
(-3,(3,7) => (3,5)),
(-1,(4,7) => (4,6)),
(-2,(4,7) => (4,5)),
(-1,(5,7) => (5,6)),
(-1,(5,7) => (5,5)),
(-1,(6,7) => (6,6)),
(-2,(6,7) => (6,5)),
(-1,(7,7) => (7,6)),
(-3,(7,7) => (7,5)),
(-1,(7,8) => (6,6)),
(-1,(7,8) => (8,6)),
(-1,(8,7) => (8,6)),
(-1,(8,7) => (8,5))]
```

so it appears that the first move it encounters is the best as far as my algorithm can tell.  Am I not going deep enough into the search tree to get anything meaningful?

Comment: I can't look at this much longer :). It's getting late. Can you stop calling maxGame and tell me what the printout of `map (\mv -> ...` is? And perhaps give the definitions of `Move`, `Coord`, and `Game`.

Comment: It seems unlikely that `evalNaive` would return 0 everywhere, and that's the only place you assign a new value to `v`. Your `node` and `helper` functions look correct. Set the depth to 1, and try running like that. Print some `eval` results. It looks like it may be somewhere in the `alphaBeta` definition. I'm not quite sure what this does: `map (\mv -> (abMinNode 4 (-100) 100 (move g mv), mv)) (nextMoves g)`. I'm not a Haskell expert at all, but I'm interested :).

Comment: So basically my functions for a given max node / min node will only return an integer for the score that it found, since that's all you care about except for the very first move. So before I kick off the recursion, I do it differently at the top level. That lambda takes each move and gives you a tuple of its score and the move itself (so you can remember what the move was).  So actually the first level isn't doing any AB pruning.

Comment: I think something is missing. It's really odd that you're getting a 0 when only evalNaive sets it. Try printing the game and eval at each horizon node.

Comment: OK, man. By some madness, I have converted the above to only integers, and called alphaBeta (with an integer in place of a game): http://pastie.org/10091140. The result is as I would expect - I get a value back equal to what evalNaive returns. I simply returned 64 in evalNaive, and that is the answer I get. The recursion is fine. Please just have evalNaive return 64, and see if that actually gets returned instead of 0 in your code. The move function may also be a problem (perhaps it wipes the board).

Comment: Another idea is to replace nextMoves with a simpler function that just returns an array of moves, though I doubt that the error lies in nextMoves.

Comment: When I get home, I will do that with evalNaive function and also post some more code.  I am actually planning on putting the project on github, so that may be more useful for this purpose as well.  My move function returns a Maybe Game, where a Nothing means that the move was not legal.  I have tested it pretty thoroughly so I don't believe it can wipe the board.

Comment: Did you get anywhere? Edit: Just saw your update to your post.

Comment: I can't really tell much unless you post the rest of your code. The algorithm you gave works for me at any depth (try my code).

Comment: https://github.com/zcleghern/hchess Full code here

Comment: I can't seem to find the definition for `loop` anywhere, or a description about it in the standard library. Where is it defined?

Comment: It is a hacky way to write clean-looking "loops" with a fold. The code I pushed to github appears to not be up to date so it may not be there.  I'll get the latest version on there this afternoon.

Comment: I see the updates, but I still don't see the loop definition.